# GMail, IMAP, oAuth 2.0 and fetching emails

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail, imap, mailcore

I want to fetch emails from a gmail account. I've managed to get the active token using oAuth 2.0 but I have no idea where to go from here. Google and stackOverflow took me here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions but I still couldn't understand how to write a simple snippet that fetch the emails in to an array for example. I thought about using MailCore that works great by itself but it doesn't use oAuth 2.0 which is a must for me so I'm stuck with the gmail imap_extensions (API?) or what ever it's suppose to be.
I've tried digging some more on google and couldn't find **anything** helpful. How could it be that there isn't even one example in objective-c regarding using Gmail IMAP via oAuth 2.0? Really strange.

Edit: I should mention that I've also came across this: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_libraries but there's no objective-c examples there

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could probably port one of the examples? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_libraries

Comment: Have you achieved ? I am also looking for same solution. Do you have any hints for it ?

Comment: Anyone found solution now? I am also looking for solution in iOS swift.